# What is this symbol?

Tags: symbols

In [this article](http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~maudin/CobordismeLagrangien.pdf) one can find the following symbol:

[image: Symbol]

I have tried to Detexify it to no avail. What is this symbol/font?

It appears many times in the following excerpt:

[image: Big image]

Comment: It's some form of “N” in Fraktur type. The exact shape is not really important; with `\usepackage{amsfonts}` or `\usepackage{amssymb}` you can get a similar one with `\mathfrak{N}`.

Comment: To me, it looks a bit similar to \Re

Comment: @egreg is right.  Compare with the wikipedia page on unoriented cobordism https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism.  The symbols are mathfrak N's in the source.

Comment: For what it's worth, detexify *does* know the symbol, although I had to click "show more" several times (probably at least five) before I found it in its suggestions. I'm not too surprised the OP couldn't find it, but it's worth noting that it *is* there. Possibly someone with a tablet and a stylus could have found it first time?

Comment: Oops, I inadvertently posted a comment as if it were an answer (in French, yet). I opined that it was the symbol for the real part of the Lagrangian, which would be decorative R rather than N.

Comment: @Au101 when I searched it there, it was the first result for me. I used a trackpad, no stylo.

Comment: @Alenanno, you must have a steadier hand - or better skills with a trackpad - than me and the OP! :P

Comment: @Au101 Well I have tried similar sites for Chinese before, so that might have helped. :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The letter is an uppercase “N” in a Fraktur style alphabet.

Unless you find a Fraktur font in which the letter has that precise shape, you can add

```
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\cobordism}{\mathfrak{N}}
```

to your preamble (also `\usepackage{amsfonts}` would suffice, but usually `amssymb` is loaded, because it gives access to a wealth of math symbols). The “exact” shape is not important, so long as the symbol is a recognizable “Fraktur N”.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\cobordism}{\mathfrak{N}}

\begin{document}

\[
\cobordism L_n \cong \pi_n(M\lambda); L_n \cong (M\tilde{\lambda}).
\]
Dans ce travail, nous rappelons le calcul de $\cobordism L_*$ et
nous calculons l'image de $\cobordism L_*$ dans le cobordisme
non-orienté $\cobordism_*$ de Thom.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, egreg. Come to think of it, it makes sense for it to be an N, for it stands for the **non**-oriented cobordism group.